# Export data into an existing csv file using php

Tags: php, sql, csv

I'm trying to get data from my data base and load it into an existing csv file i get no errors but each time i check with the file it stills empty.
this is my PHP file :

```
 <?
 $server="XXXX";
 $user="XXXX";
 $password="XXXX";
 $db="XXXX";

  mysql_connect($server,$user,$password) or die('erreur au serveur');
  mysql_select_db($db) or die('erreur db');
  if ($file=fopen('XXXX/toERP/exportfactures.csv','w')!=FALSE){
  $req='select * from facture';
  $sql = mysql_query($req);
  $cpt=1;
   $response["factures"] = array();
   $output=fopen('http://XXXXX/toERP/exportfactures.csv','w');
  if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
  // looping through all results
   // factures node
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    // temp user array
    $facture = array();
    $facture["id_fac"] = $row["id_fac"];
    $facture["id_client"] = $row["id_client"];
    $facture["id_agent"] = $row["id_agent"];
    $facture["montant"] = $row["montant"];
    $facture["type_paiement"] = $row["type_paiement"];
    $facture["id_prod"] = $row["id_prod"];
    $facture["date_vente"] = $row["date_vente"];
    // push single client into final response array
    array_push($response["factures"], $facture);
 }
 foreach ($response["factures"] as $ligne){
    var_dump($ligne);
    fputcsv($output,$ligne) or die ('erreur');
    echo $cpt."inserted";
    $cpt++;
 }
  fclose($file);
 } else {
 echo "file not found";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Problem is in your array declaration

Comment: try $file = fopen('http://XXXX/toERP/factures.csv','a')

Comment: @NIRANJAN S doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code worked for me :

```
<?
$server="mysql12.000webhost.com";
$user="a2258793_star";
$password="star123";
$db="a2258793_stores";
$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password) or die('erreur au serveur');
mysql_select_db($db) or die('erreur db');
mysql_select_db($db);
$file='toERP/factures.csv';
$fp = fopen($file,"w");
$sql = mysql_query("select * from facture") or die (mysql_error);
mysql_data_seek($sql,0);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $sep = "";
$comma = "";
foreach ($row as $name => $value)
  {
$sep.=$comma.''.str_replace('','""',$value);
$comma =";";
  }
  $sep.="\n";

  fputs($fp,$sep);
}
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to write to an http location try changing it to a local directory.

`fopen('\XXXX\toERP\factures.csv','w')`

or just change the save location

`$output = fopen('\XXXX\toERP\factures.csv','w');
fputcsv($output, explode(';',$ligne));`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition for fputcsv : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

As the second argument, you need to provide an array with fields.

$ligne in your case, is an array with one element: ['factures'] which is another array, so you need to change the foreach to match the form below :

```
foreach ($response['factures'] as $ligne)
```

Also, as others mentioned: you need to select a local resource for the filename, and make sure you have the right to write on it.

Comment: i did what you said so i get this as a result "1inserted2inserted3inserted" it's getting better but when i check the file it's empty

Comment: What you see is the result of your ECHO commands. First you need to modify the location of where you save the file. try to use var_dump($ligne) inside the foreach, so you can see what is going to be written inside the csv file

Comment: you have a syntax error. I have an error in my code. it's "foreach" not "forach". I change now

Comment: i get this array(7) { ["id_fac"]=> string(1) "1" ["id_client"]=> string(1) "1" ["id_agent"]=> string(1) "1" ["montant"]=> string(6) "340.54" ["type_paiement"]=> string(7) "especes" ["id_prod"]=> string(5) "12345" ["date_vente"]=> string(10) "2015-05-11" } 1inserted

Comment: try to change this : $file = fopen('http://XXXX/toERP/factures.csv','w') to this : $file = fopen('factures.csv','w'). Then, check if near your file you find the csv file.

Comment: please update your code here, so I can see the changes

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open a file from remote server due to url example your have wrote. This is your most possible issue if you see the lines inserted by echo.